# Who gave the "yadav rav lo" ordination a few decades ago?

Tags: history, rabbis, semicha

According to Rabbi Hoenig's article, "The Orthodox Rabbi as Military Chaplain" (*Tradition* Fall 1976, emphasis in the original):

> This situation brought up the question of
>   proper ordination, the recognition of other Yeshivot, and that
>   of individual rabbis bestowing a certificate which read
>
> וידיו **רב** לו להשפיע על דור הצעיר להורות באורחות החיים

("May his efforts succeed [play on word with "rabbi" highlighted] to influence the young[er] generation, to instruct in the ways of life.")

Any idea who gave that ordination? Who received it? What it was about? Who originated the phrase?

Comment: Re "What it was about": It sounds as though the sentences preceding what you quoted would help with that.

Comment: The context has to do with rabbis joining as chaplains who had ordinations other than the most-common RIETS/RCA one. It sounds like some individual rabbis gave this "yadav rav lo" ordination; I'm curious what its requirements were, how often this was done, and who these rabbis were (among other questions).

Comment: It's a play on [Devarim 33:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cu0511.htm) (I thought you might have figured it out but you didn't explicitly mention it, so I thought I should point it out)